# Debian wheezy hangs when installing on old laptop

Tags: linux, debian, debian-wheezy

I have a very old laptop i'm trying to install Debian wheezy on.

When running the expert install, after selecting a video mode, it hangs.

Here's a picture I tried to take of the screen after it has hung:
[https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35314071/Photo%20Dec%2016%2C%2011%2047%2044%20AM.jpg](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35314071/Photo%20Dec%2016,%2011%2047%2044%20AM.jpg)
I can try to get a better one if you can't make out what something says.

But what can I do to get the install to continue/complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to boot and install by using `acpi=off`